# Magento Magmi API import with several websites and storeviews

Tags: api, magento, magmi

I will use magmi api (not the csv file import) to import and updates products in magento in several websites and storeviews.

On

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Datapump_API

And in the samples folder I find very few example. But these examples does not show how I can set different contents (langunage data) for different storeviews.

Does any body know how this is possible with the magmi api or does anybody know a site with has snippets or have some snippets?

dermold

Comment: Moreover, could it be that the example on the link does not works? I put that script in the right dir and set the database settings in the .ini file. The scrips runs, there are no message. White page! I manuelly put an echo after the scripts and this means the script runs to the end. But there is no category added to that shop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is link to article I wrote : [LINK](http://gauss-development.com/blog/magento-mass-product-import/)
Replace the value of store ("admin") to your store identifier and 
change other values to your desired language.